# In Next.js env , can router.back() have paramter?

Tags: routes, router, next.js

`import router from 'next/router'`

`<a onClick={router.back()}> go back </a>`

---

above is the example code that I just wrote.  will there be any ways to pass parameter using `router.back()` ?

Comment: Why would you want to pass parameters to `.back()`? It doesn't make sense to rewrite history ahah

Comment: What is your use case

Comment: I want specific component to be rendered when the function router.back() is being  executed. And I do not want that specific component to be under /pages directory. Though I know there're other ways to pass parameters to render the specific component , I just want to know if it is possible to pass parameter with using 'router.back()'.